# Can a deployment ensure that there is never more than one pod running?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

If I have a deployment with only a single replica defined, can I ensure that only ever one pod is running?

I noticed that when I do something like `kubectl rollout` for a very short amount of time I will see two pods in my logs.

Comment: That is closer to what a `StatefulSet` is designed to do, especially when combined with [an `OrderedReady` P.M.P.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#orderedready-pod-management)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I have a deployment with only a single replica defined, can I ensure that only ever one pod is running?

It sounds like you are asking for "at most one Pod" semantics. Also consider what happens when a Node becomes *unresponsive*.

This is point where [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) has different behavior.

##### Deployment

Has **at least one** Pod behavior, and may scale up new pods if it is unclear it at least one is running.

##### StatefulSet

Has [**at most one**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/#statefulset-considerations) Pod behavior, and make sure to not scale up more pods if it is unclear if at most one is running.

Comment: Okay thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for