# Kubernetes Node-pressure eviction: pod's eviction/creation order

Tags: kubernetes

My main goal is to guarantee that the pod exists in a single copy.
For achieving it in deployment, I used:
 `strategy: type: Recreate`
And it works just fine.

But there's also the scheduler, that can possibly **create a new pod FIRST** and **ONLY THEN evict the old one**.

I couldn't find any info about the order of pod's eviction/creation.

It seems reasonable to evict first and only then create (because the main reason of this process is the lack of resources). But that's just a guess, not a fact.

Can somebody clarify this (special thanks for the link with the info)?
Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

> My main goal is to guarantee that the pod exists in a single copy.

You need to use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) if you want to avoid having multiple instances of your app. When using [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), Kubernetes is prioritizing *availability*, e.g. if a Node becomes unreachable, it creates new instances on other nodes.

See also [Can a deployment ensure that there is never more than one pod running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074742/can-a-deployment-ensure-that-there-is-never-more-than-one-pod-running/68075454#68075454)